# Why is my colormap/colorbar not matching what I am attempting to display?

Tags: python, montecarlo, imshow

I am attempting to create a graphic for a 1D Ising chain which appears as a row of black and white squares, representing spin up and spin down elements respectively. To do this, I am using the following code:

```
L = 100
chain = np.random.choice([-1,1], L)
new = np.reshape(chain,(1,100))
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(new, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('gray', 2))
plt.colorbar(ticks= (-1,1), label='spin', shrink = 0.25)
plt.show()
```

After running a metropolis algorithm on the system, if the system is not homogenous at the end then the code works, producing the included graphic.

[image: 1]

If, however, all of the spins are either up or down at the end, the colormap and colorbar do not behave.

[image: 2]

How do I get the color bar and map to display correctly in the case where all the elements in the array are the same?

Answer (score 0):

`imshow` sets the min/max based the the min/max of your data. When you have only one kind of spin, min and max are equal.

You need to specify the min and max values using the `vmin`/`vmax` parameters in `imshow`:

```
plt.imshow(new, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('gray', 2), vmin=-1, vmax=1)
```

[image: colorbar]

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help.